# click on row jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use link-button in grid-view for display popup appear by using this

```
 $(function () {
  $('[ID*=lbViewChart]').on('click', function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var Id = row.find('td')[0].firstChild.data;
    var obj = {};
    obj.ID = Id;
    GetData(obj);
    return false;
});
```

Now i want when user click on row then pop up appear for this i modify this code to this

**UPDATED CODE**

```
$(function () {
     $('#tabledate tr').click(function () {
    var row = $(this);
    var Id = row.find('td')[0].firstChild.data;
    var obj = {};
    obj.ID = Id;
    GetData(obj);
    return false;
});
```

but when i click on row nothing happens
any solution?

Comment: Use `var row = $(this);` instead of `var row = $(this).closest('tr');`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, result will be same and SUPER_USER I think you need `$('[ID*=tabledate] tr')`

Comment: @Satpal Yeah, confused a bit. closest will start traversing from itself.

Comment: `firstChild.data` ? What does that return ?

Comment: @Rayon this return data. there is ID column according to that ID i fetch data from database and display data in chart view in pop up

Comment: @SUPER_USER Share your mrkup/html as well...

Comment: @Rayon check update

Comment: I dont know much.. But try $(this).closest('tr').attr('id') to get which row is selected

Comment: where i put this after this  var row = $(this).html(); ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr');
```

from your code you are already on `tr`. Instead of this use:

```
var row = $(this).html();
```

Comment: i use this but nothing happens